# Crystal: multipart shard can't read from io delimeted

Tags: file, io, crystal-lang

I'm trying to write bytes to file from multipart's io, but for some reason the file is `closed`

```
  buffer = uninitialized UInt8[2048]

  File.open( "#{Config::Application::PUBLIC_DIR}/#{file_name}", "w+") do |_file|
    p "is closed?: #{uploaded_file_io.closed?}" #=> true
    if (read_bytes_length = uploaded_file_io.read(buffer.to_slice)) > 0
      _file.write( buffer.to_slice[0, read_bytes_length] )
    end
  end
```

Empty file is created, I can see it in directory, but as soon i try to write it raises that stream is closed (when reading from multiparts IO::Delimeted).

What do I do wrong?

And also if you know some guides on working with IO or files in Crystal , please share.

EDIT:
uploaded_file_io is IO::Delimeted from rx14/multipart, it is assigned in    HTTP::FormData.parse block that yields it like:

```
    HTTP::FormData.parse(request) do |field, io, meta, headers|

      #that class simply has properties, and is to store what's passed
      value_to_return[field] = MultipartFileWrapper.new(io: io, meta: meta, headers: headers) 

    end

  #later:
  uploaded_file_io = value_to_return["file"].io
```

Comment: It's kind of impossible to give you any help without knowing what is `uploaded_file_io ` and how it came into existence (it's never initialized in the snippet above)

Comment: I have updated question, to show how uploaded_file_io is initialized.

Comment: I think that once you leave the block the IO is automatically closed for you. This comment also seems to indicate that: https://github.com/RX14/multipart.cr/blob/master/src/http/formdata/parser.cr#L26-L45 (the parser is used by FormData). You should probably do all your processing inside the block.